# Why are most SwiftUI Views non-sendable?

Tags: swift, swiftui, concurrency

Why are most SwiftUI types (like Color or Text) non-sendable? Is there a specific reason for this? Isn't that kind of the point of SwiftUI views? Or am I missing something?

```swift
struct Test: Sendable {
  let color: Color // Warning: Stored property 'color' of 'Sendable'-conforming struct 'Test' has non-sendable type 'Color'
}
```

I want to store colors in a struct that needs to be sendable, but I get this warning (with concurrency checking set to complete). I don't just want to mark it `@unchecked Sendable` without knowing if it's actually safe to do so.

Comment: Since views and other UI related types should be handled by the main thread there is no reason to make them Sendable. At least that is my guess.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson IMHO, that isn't a strong reason for not being sendable - but rather a reason for being a `@MainActor`. Technically, most instances of SwiftUI views should  be "naturally" sendable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Color` is a representation of a color. Which is a `View` a type that represents part of your app’s user interface and provides modifiers that you use to configure views.

It isn't really meant to be passed around. It doesn't have any value to any other layers in the application it is strictly for presentation.

`UIColor` is an object that stores color data and sometimes opacity. This can be used across layers for different purposes.

Comment: Interesting point! That does make sense. It just feels wrong using `UIColor`, since it's part of `UIKit`, and not some other framework not relating to UI, but I guess that's just the only real way to store actual color data?

Comment: @Quantm yes, with `UIColor` you can actually get rgba values, use `Codable` to transmit using JSON. You can't do that with a `View` it is simply for show.